# Slow range forEach in Kotlin

Tags: performance, kotlin, compiler-construction

I used the following code to measure performance of different syntax constructions in Kotlin

```
fun time(what: String, body: () -> Int) {
    val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
    var sum = 0

    repeat(10) {
        sum += body()
    }

    val end = System.currentTimeMillis()

    println("$what: ${(end - start) / 10}")
}

val n = 200000000
val rand = Random()
val arr = IntArray(n) { rand.nextInt() }

time("for in range") {
    var sum = 0
    for (i in (0 until n))
        sum += arr[i]
    sum
}

time("for in collection") {
    var sum = 0
    for (x in arr)
        sum += x
    sum
}

time("forEach") {
    var sum = 0
    arr.forEach { sum += it }
    sum
}

time("range forEach") {
    var sum = 0
    (0 until n).forEach { sum += arr[it] }
    sum
}

time("sum") {
    arr.sum()
}
```

And that is the result I got:

> for in range: 84
>   for in collection: 83
>   forEach: 86
>   range forEach: 294
>   sum: 83

So my question is: Why is range forEach much slower that other syntax constructions?
It seems to me that compiler may generate equal bytecode in all cases (but does not in case of "range forEach")

Comment: Beware of JVM warmup time though. The first time a method runs, it's often not recompiled to machine code by the JVM yet. Often the second time you call the same method, it can sometimes runs multiple times as fast.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From documentation:

> [A `for` loop over a range or an array is compiled to an index-based loop that does not create an iterator object.](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#for-loops)

`forEach` as you can see at https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/for-each.html is special-cased for arrays, but has a single implementations for all `Iterable`s, so it needs to create an iterator.

Comment: So, does it mean that in case "forEach" an IntArray iterator is used and it is as fast as index-based loop without iterator?

Comment: No, the code for `IntArray.forEach` uses an index-based loop. The code for `Iterable.forEach` can't (or technically it could, but it would be very slow for many types).

Comment: Ok, thank you. As far as I understand, the answer is "Because there is no optimized forEach version for IntRange"

Comment: Yes, Kotlin developers (or you!) could add extension methods for `Range`s specifically, and it should work just as fast.

Comment: (though I haven't checked, and it depends on whether "for loop over a range" optimization works with non-literal ranges).

Answer (score 1):

The most interesting comparison is probably between these 2 cases:

Case A: taking 86 ms

```
time("forEach") {
    var sum = 0
    arr.forEach { sum += it }
    sum
}
```

Case B: taking 294 ms

```
time("range forEach") {
    var sum = 0
    (0 until n).forEach { sum += arr[it] }
    sum
}
```

While case A is actually calling `IntArray.forEach(...)` case B is calling `Iterable<T>.forEach(...)` - these are two different calls.

I guess the Kotlin compiler knows to optimize `IntArray.forEach(...)`, but not `Iterable<T>.forEach(...)`.

Comment: Both `forEach` are `inline`, there are no instances of lambdas created at runtime. Also, the `IntArray.forEach` is the fast one.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov let me understand: the "foreach" call is inlined, but a lambda expression, .e.g. `{ sum += it }` still need to be called.

Comment: Applications of lambdas in inline functions are inlined, it ends up directly in method code.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for this code. I was more interested in the performance difference between array and list and was a bit shocked to have 6 times as long running time. I thought the list is only slow in creation.

Above runtimes on my machine for comparison:

for in range: 55
for in collection: 57
forEach: 55
range forEach: 223
sum: 57

```
//code change replace IntArray with List
//val arr = IntArray(n) { rand.nextInt() }
val arr = List(n) { rand.nextInt() }
```

for in range: 383
for in collection: 367
forEach: 367
range forEach: 486
sum: 371

```
//code change replace IntArray with Array<Int>
//val arr = IntArray(n) { rand.nextInt() }
val arr: Array<Int> = Array<Int>(n) { rand.nextInt() }
```

for in range: 331
for in collection: 281
forEach: 276
range forEach: 445
sum: 313

So, the main difference is not the use Array vs List but the use of Object Int vs primitive type