# kotlin intProgression not iterating?

Tags: kotlin

Sorry this seems very basic but I'm missing something

I have a method signature  override

```
fun doSomeWork (range: IntProgression, j: Int): List<Cell>{
```

I want to iterate the range whatever it is (could be up or down say 1 to 4 or 4 down to 1).  The range itself seems to work, so on my 4 down to 1 example

```
    println (range.first.toString() + " to " + range.last.toString() + ", step = " + range.step)
```

prints "4 to 1, step = 1"

but I can't seem to iterate the range ?  I've tried a few things

```
for (i in range) {
     println ("range: $i)"
}
```

and then

```
for (i in range.first until range.last step range.step){
        println ("Loop de loop $i")
    }
```

(although writing this question I noticed it is step 1 not -1 which may be the issue here ?  but as I want to be able to pass in a range of either direction I haven't checked)

and then

```
 range.forEach { println ("range foreach") }
```

none of them print anything, but they don't throw an error so any code after that runs through properly.

Can anyone point out why I'm failing to do this entry level task ?!

Comment: so either you want an `IntProgression` from 1 to 4 with step 1, i.e. `IntProgression(1, 4, 1)` or you want a `IntProgression` from 4 to 1 with step -1, i.e. `IntProgression(4, 1, -1)`. While you wrote your question you already realised the step... but the starting point isn't `1` then, but rather `4` ;-)

Comment: All of this works as expected: `val range: IntProgression = 1.downTo(0); range.forEach { println(it) }; for (i in range) println(i)` prints `1 0 1 0`. So my advice is post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you still have problems.

Comment: Okay thanks I'll play about and then set the answer but although I can use this as what I would term a 'work around' it leaves me needing to determine the direction of the range parameter at the start of the fun doSomeWork {}.  Unless the issue  is the way I have initialised the intProgression (1..4 or 4..1) ?  I'll try using fromClosedRange...

Comment: (okay so part of the project was a typo passing in 4..1 rather than 4 downTo 1)

Comment: ... you write the function, so you define the contract for it... you shouldn't need to know whether there is coming an intProgression (1..4) or (4..1) with wrong step... that's the callers responsibility.... you just do what you know and can.... iterate it ;-)

Comment: ... or if you want/must: validate the intProgression and deal with wrong parameters accordingly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `forEach` method can be used to iterate through the `IntProgression`. The `it` can be used to get the value or index.

```
fun doSomeWork (range: IntProgression) {
    range.forEach {
        println(it)
    }
}
```

**Invoking the above method:-**

```
ClassName().doSomeWork(IntProgression.fromClosedRange(1,10, 1))
```

Comment: Thanks to all this seems the clearest although all answer the question.  I had a set of when -> calling the function and I'd left one as 4..1 instead of 4 downTo 1 following an initial misunderstanding.  The above works as expected (as does passing in 4 downTo 1 instead of 4..1)

Comment: But note that for ranges there is a good reason to prefer `for i in range` over `range.forEach` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52904923/slow-range-foreach-in-kotlin, unless it was fixed in the latest version. Not sure whether it applies when the static type is `IntProgression`.

Answer (score 5):

So you want an `IntProgression` from 4 to 1 with step -1, i.e. `IntProgression.fromClosedRange(4, 1, -1)` or better yet: `4.downTo(1)`. While you wrote your question you already realised the step... but the starting point isn't `1` then, but rather `4` ;-) With the [`downTo`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.ranges/down-to.html) such problems will not arise, as the function takes care of the direction and it's also more readable then.

Note also that you can simply use [`reversed`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.ranges/reversed.html) to reverse a progression:

```
range.reversed()
```

and either use it in a `for`-loop or with `.forEach`, etc.

So:

```
val range = IntProgression.fromClosedRange(1, 4, 1)
range.forEach(::print) // prints: 1234
range.reversed().forEach(::print) // prints: 4321
```

Answer (score 1):

```
val range= IntProgression.fromClosedRange(1, 4, 1)

for (i in range)
println(i) // out put 1234

for (i in range.reversed())
    println(i)//out put 4321
```

use

```
IntProgression.fromClosedRange(start, end, step)
```

for reverse range

```
  IntProgression.reversed()
```

more details refer [Ranges](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/ranges.html)

Comment: You should rather link the `reversed`-function instead of pasting it... otherwise one might copy that instead of using it.