# How to safely cast (no null cast) in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

```
    for (i in position until effectList.size) {
        var holder = mRecyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(i) as EffectsHolder
        holder.bindEffect(holder.effect, i)
    }
```

My code is causing a null pointer cast like this:

```
kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type com.mobileer.androidfxlab.EffectsAdapter.EffectsHolder
```

Because `mRecyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(i)` returns null. How can I conditionally cast only if `mRecyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(i)` is not null? Then I can do `holder?.bindEffect(holder.effect, i)`

Comment: You could also do `as? EffectsHolder` which will return null if the object is anything else than an `EffectsHolder`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kotlin allows you to perform a cast like this using the [Safe (nullable) Cast Operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html#safe-nullable-cast-operator):

```
val maybeString: String? = someObject as? String
```

So in your case, perhaps something like this:

```
var holder = mRecyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(i) as? EffectsHolder
holder?.bindEffect(holder?.effect, i)
```

Answer (score 2):

While Kotlin provides a safe cast operator `as?` but you still need to handle the nulls and [if you look at the bytecode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61399025/11377112), `as?` has more instructions.

So what I recommend is to use the is operator as most as possible. It does not do internal casting in the JVM, instead only checks for it and the object is actually smart-casted to the cheched type.

Example:

```kotlin
val holder = mRecyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(i)
if (holder is EffectsHolder) {
    // use `holder` here, it is smart-casted internally into EffectsHolder
}
```